# How to Connect to PXE Server From 2 Different Subnets

Tags: dhcp, pxe

I am running a Windows Server 2016 VM which itself is running Serva, a TFTP/PXE server. I have it set up properly and working, when client machines are on the same subnet. When they're on a different subnet, the DHCP request times out and nothing progresses. I had IT enable Option 066 on the primary DHCP and on the VPN devices, that also acts as DHCP servers, for two different subnets. Despite this, clients on these different subnets never get through. Assuming that I can't have one server on each subnet, is there any way to make this work?

The server can have multiple NICs and I was considering assigning each additional NIC with IP information from those subnets, so LAN Connection 2 would have the IP/Subnet/Gateway info as a machine on the second subnet and LAN Connection 3 would have the info for the third subnet. I would then coordinate with IT to change the Option 66 value on each VPN changed to the PXE/TFTP server IP as it appears on that subnet. Would this approach work? If not, what other options could I consider?

Answer (score 1):

DHCP/proxyDHCP traffic is stopped at router devices. In order to make the thing work you must set up IP Helpers for DHCP and proxyDHCP traffic (DHCP relay) on every involved router.

Forget about using DHCP option 66; that is handled by Serva.